# How to provide a function for the other program to call it?

Tags: c++, linux, system

Assume I use a C++ program to maintain a queue in Linux, and do some things with the data in the queue, and now I want to run it in the background and provide a function, therefore other programs could simply call it to pull a data into my queue.
What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your programs are running as two separate processes, You cannot just call functions in other process directly, you will need a **Interprocess communication Mechanism(IPC)** to communicate between the two processes.

Usually, this is done as follows:
The process which you want to communicate to provides a client side library, The process or application which wants to communicate with the process links to this client side library. This client side library provides simple function calls which your calling process/application can call directly. The client side library implements the necessary IPC mechanism to communicate with the remote process.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you want a client API that wraps communication with the queue.

You need to create a separate library that contains and exports the API, and include it in the programs that want to use it.

```
class Communicator
{
public:
    bool putData(Data* data);
    bool getData(Data*& data);
};
```

The implementation of `Communicator` does the actual communication with the queue via IPC, but you abstract that layer out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of mechanisms to do this, from creating your own server, using IPC, RPC, CORBA to name a few.

As to the best it depends on a variety of factors.

In the OP you mentioned you want a queue with one process processing it - perhaps using shared memory and a mutex would be a simple solution, with a library to access the queue for both processes.